# Where is ruby gem specifying the ruby version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Building a simple gem, using echoe, just doing something like

```
rake manifest 
rake gem
gem install
```

There's nothing in the generated files (or anywhere in the project, for that matter) where I'm referencing or specifying a ruby version, but trying to install my gem gives me a "requires ruby >= 1.9" message.

So, where is the ruby version being derived? (the generated gemspec does contain the lines

```
s.required_rubygems_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">= 1.2") if ...
s.rubygems_version = %q{1.3.5}
```

if that's at all relevant - only references I could find with any version information at all)

Answer (score 1):

Check in `gem` itself. Looking at `/usr/bin/gem` on my machine gives me this on line 12.

```
required_version = Gem::Requirement.new ">= 1.8.6"
```

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks. However that yields "1.8.3" on my machine (that refers to the ruby version?) - a good thing, since a hardcoded requirement of 1.9 on a machine w/o 1.9 wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: True, it wouldn't make sense unless there were some strange versioning issues with ruby installations--personally I have multiple versions of ruby installed on the same machine without using rvm. If someone wasn't careful, I can imagine this being an issue. But to answer your question, yes, this refers to the version of ruby that gem is able to find.